# sort vector by string length and occurrence

Tags: c++

What I'm trying to do is change this sort

There is a map < string,int> and it is sorted by frequency

```
typedef map<string,int> word_Count_List; 
word_Count_List word_Count; 

struct val_Lessthan : binary_function < pair<string,int>, pair<string,int>, bool > {
bool operator() (const pair<string,int>& x, const pair<string,int>& y) const
{return x.second>y.second;}
} val_lt;
```

and later

```
vector<pair<string,int> > wordVector;
copy(word_Count.begin(), word_Count.end(), back_inserter(wordVector));

sort(wordVector.begin(), wordVector.end(), val_lt);
```

I want to print a list of words with their occurrence(which it does now) but change the compare to int * string.length, instead of just int

This is how i'm printing it at the moment

```
ofstream file_Out;
file_Out.open(file);
for(unsigned int i=0; i<wordVector.size(); ++i) {

   file_Out << wordVector[i].first << " " << wordVector[i].second << "\n";
   }

 file_Out.close();  
}
```

I'm not too good with structs and overloading, can I change the one above or do I need to do something new?

Is it legal to do something like

```
 {return (x.first.length*x.second)>(y.first.length*y.second);}
```

Comment: Code review comment: `vector<pair<string,int> > wordVector; copy(word_Count.begin(), word_Count.end(), back_inserter(wordVector));` can be better expressed as: `vector<pair<string,int> > wordVector(word_Count.begin(), word_Count.end());` (unless you care to call `reserve` between the two lines

Comment: Other than that, I am not sure I understand the problem... so instead of comparing `x.second` you wan to compare `x.second * x.first.size()`? Have you tried just substituting that in `val_Lessthan`?

Comment: You should say whether the sort should consider *only* the string length *or* the string length and then - within strings of equal length - their frequency.

Comment: Ya, so the problem wasn't that hard after all, I guess just typing this post helped me think. thanks for the code review though.